# set cursor property to hand for both values (ie.true and false)

Tags: wpf

In my style I want to set the cursor value to Hand for both values, for true and false.

Is there any way to set this?

```
<Style TargetType="Image">
  <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource SOff}"/>
     <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        </Trigger>                                       
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource SOff}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource SOn}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: They you dont need a trigger. Just set Cursor="Hand" for the control.

Comment: You dont need trigger as in either case you are setting value Hand. So whats the point of using triggers?

Comment: as my value changes from true to false or reverse.i have to change image .when my value is true cursor type is set to hand ,but for false value cursor type not set to hand..

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you don't need any triggers for this behavior.  Just set the cursor property on the style.

```
<Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
```